# Как получить ответ в формате Json в Web Api Net Core 6?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core-webapi

Создал проект Web Api .Net Core 6.Добавил подключение к БД MySQL и написал метод получения продуктов. Ответ получается в браузере в виде массива [ и там данные ].Как мне конвертировать мой ответ в формат Json.Библиотеку AddNewtonsoftJson установил
В инете пишут что нужно писать это в WebConfig но его у меня  нет
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот сам контроллер и метод

```
[ApiController]
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("[controller]")]
   
public class ProductsController : 
    ControllerBase
{
    private readonly FlebocombinatBioContext _context;

    public ProductsController(FlebocombinatBioContext context)
    {
       _context = context;
    }

    // GET: Products
  
    [HttpGet("Index")]
   
    public async Task<ActionResult<List<Product>>> Get()
    {
        var context=new FlebocombinatBioContext();
        var List = await context.Products.Select(s => new Product { 
            Id= s.Id,
            Description= s.Description,
            Energyvalue= s.Energyvalue,
            Expirationdate= s.Expirationdate,
            Image = s.Image,
            Nutritionalvalue= s.Nutritionalvalue,
            Price = s.Price,
           
            ProductTypeId = s.ProductTypeId,
            Sostav = s.Sostav,
            Title = s.Title,
            Ves= s.Ves
            
            

        }
        ).ToListAsync();
        if (List.Count < 0)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        else
        {
            return List ;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Вы перепутали ASP.NET и ASP.NET Core. Инструкции читаете для одного, а используете другое. Newtonsoft не нужен, есть встроенный Syste.Text.Json. Но это нюансы, а делается это так `return Json(List);` Еще форматом ответа можно управлять с клиента через заголовок Accept в запросе https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting

Comment: Спасибо!Да бывает такое когда пытаешься освоить Net Core

Comment: _Ответ получается в браузере в виде массива [ и там данные ]_ - это и есть JSON.